# Help with finding the equation of line tangent to the semi circle with the equation: $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

[image]

Ok so I need to show that the equation of the tangent above to the semi-circle with the equation: $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$,  is $y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x$ + $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

What we from the question:

The tangent intersects the $x$-axis at $(2,0)$, (assume that you do not know any other points of intersection)

What I tried to do so far:

Since its a tangent, I decided to differentiate the semi-circle function using the chain rule, getting:

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ = $\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Then using the equation of a line formula:

$y=mx+c$

--> $y=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x +c$

Substituting the point in:

-->$0=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{1-2^2}}(2) +c$

Now clearly something is wrong because I will get the square root of a negative, which does not make any sense. Need help from here.

*Note: I know that there are other ways to solve this, but I would prefer if calculus was used to solve this question.

Comment: You don't know the point of tangency yet. Keep in mind it's not at (2,0) which is what you used to calculate the slope of the given tangent.

Comment: @randomgirl But I got the equation of the line, so shouldn't (2,0) be a point which that line satisfies?

Comment: The derivative of the curve gives only the slope (formula) of the tangent lines using only points along it's curve (if the tangent exists at said point-it does here.)

Comment: To perhaps clarify @randomgirl's comment: Let's mark up your "$y = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x+c$" as $$y_{\text{line}} = \frac{-x_{\text{circle}}}{\sqrt{1-x_{\text{circle}}^2}}x_{\text{line}}+c \text{.}  $$  "$x_{\text{circle}}$" must be the $x$-coordinate of a point on the circle to get the slope through that point.  "$x_{\text{line}}$" and "$y_{\text{line}}$ must be the coordinates of a point on the line.  So the only time your substitution is correct is at the one point where the line and circle intersect, which is not what you did.

Comment: @EricTowers I understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly found that the derivative is
$$y' = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$$
The point-slope form of the equation of the tangent line is
$$y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$$
where $m$ is the slope and $(x_0, y_0)$ is a point on the tangent line.  Since the tangent line passes through the point $(2, 0)$, it satisfies the equation
$$y - 0 = m(x - 2)$$
Substituting $-\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$ for $m$ and $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$ for $y$ yields
$$\sqrt{1 - x^2} = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}(x - 2)$$
Solve the above equation for $x$ in order to find the $x$-coordinate of the point of tangency, then substitute that value of $x$ into the equation $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ to find its $y$-coordinate.  The slope of the tangent line is found by evaluating the derivative at the point of tangency.

Comment: Nicely done! I understand your method. I had a question: I knew the gradient of the line and a point, so why can't I use point (2,0) which the line must satisfy in the $y=mx+c$ form to solve for $c$.

Comment: The slope of the tangent line is equal to the derivative of the line at the point of tangency.  The point $(2, 0)$ is not the point at which the line is tangent to the circle.

Answer (score 2):

If we construct the radius from the center of the circle to the point of intersection, this radius, the line and the x axis forms a right triangle with angle $\theta$ at the origin.

$\sec \theta = 2$

The point of intersection is $(\cos \theta, \sin\theta) = (\frac 12, \frac {\sqrt 3}{2})$

The line intersects the y-axis at $(0,\csc \theta) = \frac {2}{\sqrt 3}$

In intercept-intercept form: $\frac {x}{2} + \frac {y\sqrt 3}{2} = 1$

Or in standard form  $x + y\sqrt 3 = 2$

If you really want to use calculus, we have:

$\frac {dy}{dx} = -\frac {x}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} = -\frac {x}{y}$

And this slope must equal the slope of the line from $(2,0)$ to $(x,y)$

$\frac {y-0}{x-2} = -\frac {x}{y}\\
y^2 = -x^2 + 2x\\
1-x^2 = -x^2 + 2x\\
x = \frac {1}{2}$

$y = -\frac {1}{\sqrt 3}(x-2)$

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$OA = (\cos t, \sin t)$ and $AB = (2 - \cos t, -\sin t)$. For $OA \perp AB$, we need the dot product $\cos t(2 - \cos t) + \sin t \cdot - \sin t = 0 \implies 2 \cos t - 1 = 0, t = \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Thus the line segment $AB = \left(\frac{3}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt3}{2} \right)$, which has slope $-\frac{\sqrt3}{3}$ and passes through $(\cos \pi/3, \sin \pi/3) = (1/2, \sqrt3/2)$.

---

Here is a non-calculus method for reference:

We know that $OA = 1, OB = 2$ and $\angle OAB$ is right since it is tangent to the circle.

Thus $\cos \angle AOB = \frac{1}{2} \implies \angle AOB = \pi/3$. Thus the gradient of $OA$ is $\text{rise}/\text{run} = \tan \pi/3 = \sqrt{3}$, and so $AB$ has a gradient of $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

$AB$ must pass through $A$ which is $(\cos \pi/3, \sin \pi/3) = (1/2, \sqrt3/2)$, therefore the equation is:

$$y - \sqrt3/2 = -\frac{1}{\sqrt3} \left(x - \frac{1}{2} \right) \implies y = -\frac{1}{\sqrt3}x + \frac{1 + (\sqrt{3})^2}{2\sqrt3}$$

Comment: oh, yeah that makes sense,  I forgot that multiple radii can exist from the centre to circumference. This was also a good solution, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Your original equation can be restated as $y^2 = 1 - x^2$.  Using implicit differentiation,
$$  2y y' = -2x x'  \text{.}  $$
Specializing the independent variable to $x$, we obtain
$$  2y \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = -2x  \text{,}  $$
so
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{-x}{y}  \text{.}  $$

So let's run our finger, the variable $a$, along the semicircle as $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$ and see where the tangent line meets the $x$-axis.  We have the point $(a,\sqrt{1-a^2})$ and the slope $\frac{-a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$, so the line is
$$  y - \sqrt{1-a^2} = \frac{-a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}(x-a)  \text{.}  $$
To pass through the point $(2,0)$, we must satisfy
$$  0 - \sqrt{1-a^2} = \frac{-a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}(2-a)  \text{,}  $$
which we can solve for $a$.  \begin{align*}
    - \sqrt{1-a^2} &= \frac{-a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}(2-a)  \\
    - (1-a^2) &= -a(2-a)  \\
    a^2 - 1 &= a^2 - 2a  \\
    1 &= 2a  \\
    a &= 1/2  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Therefore, the equation of the line is
$$  y - \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{-1/2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}}}\left( x-\frac{1}{2} \right)  \text{.}  $$
(This simplifies a little, which I leave to the reader.)